# How do I import a GitHub library into my android studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

I am trying to use this GitHub library: https://github.com/JonnyHaystack/build-prop-tools in my Android Studio Project, but can't quite figure out how to do so.

I've tried cloning the project, then importing it as a module, yet I am not sure what part of the cloned folder I am supposed to import.[image]

After I import a new module, I know I will then be able to add it as a dependency, but I do not know how to get past this step. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this library is 7 years old, i'm not sure you really should be using this

Comment: @a_local_nobody The functions seem simple, and most likely still functional on my targetSDK. Furthermore, I would like to know the general process for doing this in the future, as I have faced this problem before.

Comment: usually you add the project as a gradle dependency, most projects [tell you how to do it](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Github get from version control

[image]

2. Clone project
   [image]

Comment: I have already cloned the project, and I am wondering how to import it as a module into my project, because the "Finish" button is grayed out in Android Studio when I try to do so.

Comment: Your question in the title doesn't ask this. Your question "How do I import a GitHub library into my android studio project?"